# Why ReactiveSwift Action just run one time?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I want to implement a simple login feature using ReactiveSwift.

Here is my code for ViewController:

```
func setupRac() {
    viewmodel = SignInViewModel()

    self.viewmodel.username <~ self.usernameTextField.reactive.continuousTextValues
    self.viewmodel.password <~ self.passwordTextField.reactive.continuousTextValues

    self.loginButton.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(viewmodel.submit) { sender in
        return (self.usernameTextField.text, self.passwordTextField.text)
    }
```

The ViewModel:

```
class SignInViewModel {
let username = MutableProperty<String?>(nil)
let password = MutableProperty<String?>(nil)

let usernameValid: Property<Bool>
let passwordValid: Property<Bool>
let valid: Property<Bool>
let submit: Action<(String?, String?), String, NetworkError>

init() {
    self.usernameValid = username.map {
        return ($0 ?? "").characters.count > 0
    }

    self.passwordValid = password.map {
        return ($0 ?? "").characters.count > 0
    }

    self.valid = Property.combineLatest(self.usernameValid, self.passwordValid).map({ (usernameValid, passwordValid) in
        return usernameValid && passwordValid
    })

    self.submit = Action(enabledIf: self.valid, { username, password in
        return MembershipManager.sharedInstance.signin(username: username!, password: password!)
    })
}
```

When I put breakpoint to the line `return MembershipManager.sharedInstance.signin(...`, it's just hit one time when I press the login button only. After that, when I press the button again, nothing happen.

Does anyone know the reason why? I just started with ReactiveSwift only.

Comment: When an action is executing, you can't start a new action. Are you sure that the `MembershipManager.sharedInstance.signin()` completes before you press the button again?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the "complete" concept in Reactive. I have a wrapper class above the Alamofire, and it returns a SignalProduct (another guy wrote this code, but I cannot contact him). Anyway, I'm sure that the request has been executed, and completed.

Comment: is this code available somewhere to take a look at it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the source here. I will update my question tonight. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the [`logEvents`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Documentation/DebuggingTechniques.md#debugging-event-streams) operator to see the events sent on `MembershipManager.sharedInstance.signin` to check if there is a `.completed` event after signin.